# jQuery combine var into a string

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
var first = jQuery(this).data("first");     
var second = jQuery(this).data("second");  
var third = jQuery(this).data("third "); 

if(typeof first !== 'undefined' && first != ''){
   alert ("Done");
};
if(typeof second !== 'undefined' && second != ''){
   alert ("Done");
};
if(typeof third !== 'undefined' && third != ''){
   alert ("Done");
};
```

Here, regardless which variable is available, it will show the alert as all of them satisfy the condition.

To reduce the redundancy, I was thinking of making a var that contains all three variables then use this `total` variable to meet the condition:

```
var first = jQuery(this).data("first"); // has character 1      
var second = jQuery(this).data("second");  // has character 2
var third = jQuery(this).data("third "); // has character 3

var total = first, second, third; ?????

if(typeof total !== 'undefined' && total != ''){
   alert ("Done");
};
```

So, if one of the variables is available then, it meets the condition.

Of course the above code doesn't work. Could someone give me a hand? Thanks bunch!

Steve

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qvq0s4nb/1/

Comment: Well, thing is, there are alot more variables than 3, and I want to find a way to simplify them (ie, `total` variable that contains all other variables)

Comment: A good way of handling multiple variables in a single object is OOP programming (Prototype, native support) do not be afraid to go through the tutorials, they are easy and might help you a lot: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to check if at least one of the three variables is not null/not empty

--or `if (first && second && third)` if you want all three to be not null.

```js
var first = jQuery(this).data("first"); // has character 1      
var second = jQuery(this).data("second"); // has character 2
var third = jQuery(this).data("third "); // has character 3


if (first || second || third) {
  console.log("Done");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a `total` variable with `first || second || third` and I am getting the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
switch(true){
 case (typeof first !== 'undefined' && first != ''):
   alert('done first');
   break;
 case (typeof second!== 'undefined' && second != ''):
   alert('done second');
   break;
 case (typeof third!== 'undefined' && third != ''):
   alert('done third');
   break;
 default:
   alert('not done');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cpz8h58n/)

```
var first = jQuery(this).data("first"); // has character 1      
var second = jQuery(this).data("second");  // has character 2
var third = jQuery(this).data("third "); // has character 3

var checkArray = [first, second, third];

if(typeof total !== 'undefined' && $.inArray(total, checkArray) > -1){
    console.log("Done");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it will be to use an array and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any one property matches the condition like

```
var self = this,
  flag = ['first', 'second', 'third'].some(function(item) {
    var val = jQuery(this).data(item);
    return val !== undefined && val !== '';
  });

if (flag) {
  alert("Done");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you have too many variables** to do an "OR" check you can do this:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("first"));    
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("second"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("third"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("fourth"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("fifth"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("sixth"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("seventh"));
arr.push(jQuery(this).data("eighth"));
// add any other here

if(arr.join('').length){
    console.log('Done');
}
```